# Modify Desktop Right Click Menu

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 22.04

Running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a Dell XPS8950.
When I right click on my desktop I see this menu:

[image: Desktop menu]

Simple question is: How do I customize this menu? For example, I do not want to use Files - aka Nautilus - as my file manager so I want to switch it to Thunar (which I have installed and working). I would also like to add some additional options.

Thanks and Regards

Nigel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify this menu without editing source code of the Gnome Shell extension "Desktop Icons", which is what provides the icons on the desktop and the right-click menu.

You can change your default file manager systemwide, but that will be of no help if the extension did hard-code the file manager, which it probably does because of the need for integration on the default Gnome desktop.

Comment: Really? Well that blows - way to go with the shortsightedness who ever "designed" such a FUBAR "feature". Just about every UI I had worked with over the last 40+ years has been done with an editable "menu" file. Up to this point I really wondered why people were constantly complaining about Gnome. Now I'm starting to get it.

Comment: If a better answer comes, then please accept that one, otherwise this one may be it.